# Moving a JPanel Image with a random number

Tags: java

I'm making a racing car game for my class and I've only been programming in java for a few weeks and so I'm wondering how I could get my cars moving at different speeds using specifically a random number.

```
package racing.game;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class RacingGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int temp ;
        int dist1 = 0;
        int dist2 = 0;
        int dist3 = 0;
        int dist4 = 0;
        int i = 0;

        JFrame freRace = new JFrame();
        freRace.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        freRace.setSize(1900, 1080);
        freRace.setLayout(null);

        //Creating the vehicles
        JLabel labelCar1 = new JLabel();
        labelCar1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("images/car1.jpg"));
        labelCar1.setBounds((0), (50), labelCar1.getPreferredSize().width, labelCar1.getPreferredSize().height);
        freRace.add(labelCar1);

        JLabel labelCar2 = new JLabel();
        labelCar2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("images/car2.jpg"));
        labelCar2.setBounds((0), (310), labelCar2.getPreferredSize().width, labelCar2.getPreferredSize().height);
        freRace.add(labelCar2);

        JLabel labelCar3 = new JLabel();
        labelCar3.setIcon(new ImageIcon("images/car3.jpg"));
        labelCar3.setBounds((0), (580), labelCar3.getPreferredSize().width, labelCar3.getPreferredSize().height);
        freRace.add(labelCar3);

        JLabel labelCar4 = new JLabel();
        labelCar4.setIcon(new ImageIcon("images/car4.jpg"));
        labelCar4.setBounds((0), (900), labelCar4.getPreferredSize().width, labelCar4.getPreferredSize().height);
        freRace.add(labelCar4);

        JLabel labelBackground = new JLabel();
        labelBackground.setIcon(new ImageIcon("images/race track.jpg"));
        labelBackground.setBounds((0), (0), labelBackground.getPreferredSize().width, labelBackground.getPreferredSize().height);
        freRace.add(labelBackground);
        freRace.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        // freRace.setVisible(true);
        while (dist1 <= 1890) {

            Random rn = new Random();  

            dist1 = dist1 + rn.nextInt(5);
            dist2 = dist2 + rn.nextInt(4);
            dist3 = dist3 + rn.nextInt(3);
            dist4 = dist4 + rn.nextInt(2);
            labelCar1.setBounds((dist1), (50), labelCar1.getPreferredSize().width, labelCar1.getPreferredSize().height);
            labelCar2.setBounds((dist2), (310), labelCar2.getPreferredSize().width, labelCar2.getPreferredSize().height);
            labelCar3.setBounds((dist3), (580), labelCar3.getPreferredSize().width, labelCar3.getPreferredSize().height);
            labelCar4.setBounds((dist4), (900), labelCar4.getPreferredSize().width, labelCar4.getPreferredSize().height);
            freRace.setVisible(true);  
        } 
    }
}
```

The code is meant to get cars racing on the screen at random different speeds but I do not know which loop to choose for this and how I could make he cars speeds move randomly so i completley guessed

Comment: Get  `freRace.setVisible(true);`  out of your while, and use a thread for the loop, changing the location randomly is not a speed, to implement a speed you need  to fix it first, like `x`, then try to refresh the frame accordingly every second.

Comment: JLabel is not a good option for making games with animation. Custom paintings will be a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wondering how I could get my cars moving at different speeds using specifically a random number

You need a `speed` property for each Car. Instead of creating a list of speed values for each car. It will be easier if the property is self-contained within the Car object itself:

```
class Car{
    private double speed;
}
```

To move the cars, you can add a move method:

```
class Car{
    private int x;
    private int y;
    //private JLabel image;    //Better to use BufferedImage
    private double speed;

    //constructor not shown
    public void moveForward(){
        x += speed;
    }

    public void moveBackward(){
        x -= speed;
    }
}
```

Then you can have an array or a list of Cars:

```
ArrayList<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
```

To randomize the car's speed, just assign a random value to the car:

```
//Example
Random rnd = new Random();
car.setSpeed(rnd.nextInt(5)+1);  //random speed of 1 to 5
```

To move all the cars:

```
//Example
for(Car c : cars)
    c.moveForward();
```

If time is on your side, it is actually worth while to explore how to implement this without using `JLabels`, but instead, implement it with custom drawings.

Answer (score 0):

If you loop in the main method, you will only see the last result of the movement, you may do something like this:

```
 freRace.setVisible(true);
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
        Random rn = new Random();  
        int s1 = rn.nextInt(5);
        int s2 = rn.nextInt(5);
        int s3 = rn.nextInt(5);
        int s4 = rn.nextInt(5);
       while (dist1 <= 1890) {
        dist1 = dist1 + s1;
        dist2 = dist2 + s2;
        dist3 = dist3 + s3;
        dist4 = dist4 + s4;
        labelCar1.setBounds((dist1), (50), labelCar1.getPreferredSize().width, labelCar1.getPreferredSize().height);
        labelCar2.setBounds((dist2), (310), labelCar2.getPreferredSize().width, labelCar2.getPreferredSize().height);
        labelCar3.setBounds((dist3), (580), labelCar3.getPreferredSize().width, labelCar3.getPreferredSize().height);
        labelCar4.setBounds((dist4), (900), labelCar4.getPreferredSize().width, labelCar4.getPreferredSize().height);
        freRace.invalidate();
        try { Thread.sleep(100); } catch (Exception e) {}
       } 
     }
 }).start();
```

Note that I also added a timer so it can move constantly.

Also, is adivisable to learn how to do this in the method onPaintComponent of a JPanel so you can benefit from double-buffering.